# Jersey, How to do a post request creating a list of objects , in json format?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, moxy

I have an object

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Document {

private String docCode;
private String status;

public Document(){}
//Getters and setters   
}
```

I need to create post request to send a List of above object:
I am using a wrapper class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "bflDocuments")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BflDocumentData {

@XmlElement
private  List<BflDocument> documents;

//Getters and setters
}
```

Client Code which is used to create the post request:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
String baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/SampleRestService/webapi/documents/";
WebTarget postListWebTarget = client.target(baseURL).path("/createList").path("/jsontest");
List<Document> list = new ArrayList<Document>();
list.add(new BflDocument("Code3","Status1"));
list.add(new BflDocument("Code4","Status2"));
list.add(new BflDocument("Code5","Status3"));
DocumentData docs = new DocumentData();
docs.setDocuments(list);
Response response = postListWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(docs));
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

Above approach is creating a JSON payload as below:

```
{"documents":[{"docCode":"Code1","status":"Status1"},{"docCode":"Code2","status":"Status2"}]}
```

But the JSON payload required is:

```
[{"docCode":"Code1","status":"Status1"},{"docCode":"Code2","status":"Status2"}]
```

How the change the JSON payload according to the requirement?
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Random guess: try `docs.setDocuments(Collections.singletonList(list));`

Comment: Collections.singletonList(list) returns List<List<Document>>  which is not applicable for setDocuments method in  DocumentData  class